# Upgrading from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 black screen on reboot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, 22.04

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 but after restarting the PC after the installation I just got a black screen. I have an HP-Pavillion model 15-cs0989nl with an Nvidia GeForce. Maybe it has something to do with the Nvidia drivers but when I try to enable the networking in recovery mode to try and reinstall the drivers, it is not working and I cannot access the internet (trying to do "ip link" I get 'qdisc no queue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default'). I'm a newbie and I'm not sure how to proceed.